# Connecting slicer for boxplot with other pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to connect slicer for a boxplot sourcing data from the same table as the other pivot tables? I tried to report connection of my slicer for boxplot, but that feature seems to not available. And if not, is there a way to make a boxplot using pivot table?

Comment: https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/34319779-boxplot-chart-should-work-as-pivot-chart-too It seems an known issue in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly box, XY and scatter plots cannot be made from pivot tables. The reason I think for this is the pivot row and columns are too flexible and Excel cannot reliably decide how to do those plots for any arbitrary pivot table configuration.

You can however make a static copy of the pivot table (copy and paste values into a new sheet), then box plot from there. If you need "live" data from the pivot, you have two options. You can record a macro that repeats the static copy and paste actions and assign a keyboard shortcut. This will effectively refresh your box chart based on the current pivot chart. Alternatively you can use the GETPIVOTDATA function to extract live data from the pivot table into normal cells. The easiest way to do this is to select an normal empty cell next to the pivot table, press "=" then click with your mouse on the pivot table cell you want. You cannot "copy down" this formula, so either you must link each cell individually or try to specify the GETPIVOTDATA formula in more generic terms with self-updating references.